# Printing list containing a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to store a string variable containg some names, I want to store the respective variable in a list and print it, but am unable print the values which are stored in variable.

```
name='vsb','siva','anand','soubhik'  #variable containg some names

lis=['name'] # storing the variable in a list

for x in lis:

 print(x) #printing the list using loops
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Do you understand `'name'` just a string and not the variable `name` ?

Comment: yes!
but i've stored some values in that names,i want to store them in a list

Comment: ... `list(name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dictionary? Try this

```
variable_1 = "aa"
variable_2 = "bb"
lis = {}
lis['name1'] = variable_1   
lis['name2'] = variable_2

for i in lis:
    print(i)
    print(lis[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` variable is actually a **tuple**.

Example of tuple declaration:

```
tup1 = ('physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000)
tup2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
tup3 = "a", "b", "c", "d"
```

Example of list declaration:

```
list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
list3 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

For a better understanding you should read [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) or do a tutorial.

For your problem maybe the dictionary is the solution:

```
# A tuple is a sequence of immutable Python objects
name='vsb','siva','anand','soubhik'

print('Tuple: ' + str(name)) # ('vsb', 'siva', 'anand', 'soubhik')

# This is a list containing one element: 'name'
lis=['name']

print('List: ' + str(lis)) # ['name']

# Dictionry with key 'name' and vlue ('vsb','siva','anand','soubhik')
dictionary={'name':name}

print('Dictionary: ' + str(dictionary))

print('Dictionary elements:')
print(dictionary['name'])


print('Tuple elements:')
for x in name:
 print(x)

print('List elements:')
for x in lis:
 print(x)
```

**Output**

```
Tuple: ('vsb', 'siva', 'anand', 'soubhik')
List: ['name']
Dictionary: {'name': ('vsb', 'siva', 'anand', 'soubhik')}
Dictionary elements:
('vsb', 'siva', 'anand', 'soubhik')
Tuple elements:
vsb
siva
anand
soubhik
List elements:
name
```